# Core Plot numberForPlot will not take value greater than 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am having a first attempt at rendering a bar chart in an iphone app using core plot.
I successfully following the tutorial here: 
and was able to render the bar values.

I then proceeded to change the code to show values of objects that are specific to my app (called 'invoices').
An invoice has an NSNumber value called 'totalCost'. This is what I want to show on my graph.

I have found that if I have a totalCost value between 0 and 1, the bar will show up on the graph correctly. However, if I have a value greater than 1 the bar will not show at all.
I have tried all sorts of type conversions between floats, unsigned ints etc. and I have debugged the code and confirmed that the invoice.totalCost is always revealing the correct NSNumber value.

Also, my y-axis range is currently set to about 70, so the values above 1 should not be out of range.

Here's the code snippet:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:  (NSUInteger)index {
    Invoice *invoice = [self.invoices objectAtIndex:index];
    return invoice.totalCost;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the `fieldEnum` parameter. This method will be called at least twice for each data index, once for the bar location and again for the bar tip value.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSNumber *num = nil;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            num = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            num = ((Invoice *)[self.invoices objectAtIndex:index]).totalCost;
            break;
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. I was returning `[NSDecimalNumber zero]` earlier on but that was not giving the expected behavior.